# How to draw nodes from a txt file using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, coordinates

So basically, I have a tikzpicture and I would like to include 36 node inside this picture.
currently, the only way I know to include them is to write

```
\filldraw[blue] (3.8,3.6) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west]{};
```

I really dont want to do this for all the 36 nodes. I have the coordinates for the 36 nodes in a txt file, so is there a way to read them and draw them automatically? I don't want to connect the points to each other so it is not a path or line plotting.

this is an example of how the points are written in the txt file

0 .1

.1 0

.5 0.5

0.4 .9
and so on

I tried doing this but I didn't work

```
\foreach \x \y  in table {GPs.txt}
\draw[blue] (\x,\y) circle (1pt) node[anchor=west]{};
```

This is how I am generating my picture

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% TikZ
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{external}

% Pgfplots
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}

\newcommand{\sinv}{s\textsuperscript{$-1$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=gray!10] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
\draw [fill=red!10] (5,0) -- (4.5,0) arc [start angle=0, delta angle=90, radius=4.5] (0,4.5) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- (5,0) ;
\draw (2.5,0) -- (2.5,5);
\draw (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5);
\draw (3.1820,3.1820) -- (5,5);
%\draw (5,2.5) node[anchor=south] {.};
\filldraw[black] (5,2.5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (5,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (2.5,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (5,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (0,5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (4.5,0) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (0,4.5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (3.7417,2.5) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\filldraw[black] (2.5,3.7417) circle (2pt) node[anchor=west]{};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: It depends on what you aim to achieve. Do you want the result to be a scatter plot that is created using PGFplots? Or do you rather want to draw a Ti*k*Z picture where these coordinates represent, say, the position of items on a canvas? A lot of things are possible and for some of these, there are already nice solutions on this site. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: Thank you Jasper, I already edited the post, can you check it please?

Comment: It would be nice to have some [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which we can work with, so we know what you setup looks like. Could you provide this? You may want to do a search for `\pgfplotstableread`.

Comment: I posted a MWE, please check it. I am not sure if my question is currently clear or not, but I am sorry for not explaining my problem at the beginning with the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to employ the functionality of PGFplots which provides functions to read data from files, you can make use of the mechanics provided by the package `pgfplotstable`. Note that `pgfplotstable` loads `pgfplots` and `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, therefore you only load one of these packages.

Using this approach, you first need to read the data from the file using `\pgfplotstableread` and store it in some variable. Then you can calculate the number of rows and loop over the rows using `\foreach`. With the help of `\pgfplotstablegetelem`, you can then grab the relevant coordinate from the table data.

I simplified some parts of your code.

```
\begin{filecontents}{GPs.dat}
0 .1
.1 0
.5 0.5
0.4 .9 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[fill=gray!10] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
\draw[fill=red!10] (5,0) -- (4.5,0) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=90, radius=4.5] 
    -- (0,4.5) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- cycle;
\draw (2.5,0) -- (2.5,5)
      (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5)
      (3.1820,3.1820) -- (5,5);
\foreach \x/\y in {5/2.5, 5/5, 2.5/5, 5/0, 0/5, 4.5/0, 0/4.5, 3.7417/2.5, 2.5/3.7417} {
    \filldraw[black] (\x,\y) circle[radius=2pt];
}

\pgfplotstableread{GPs.dat}\loadedtable

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\loadedtable}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\loadedtablerowcount{\pgfplotsretval-1} 

\foreach \i in {0,...,\loadedtablerowcount}{
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\pgfplotsretval}
    \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]1}\of{\loadedtable}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{\pgfplotsretval}
    \draw[blue] (\x,\y) circle (1pt);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A solution using PGFplots could be as follows:

```
\begin{filecontents}{GPs.dat}
0 .1
.1 0
.5 0.5
0.4 .9 
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis equal,
    axis line style={draw=none},
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=5,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=5,
    clip=false,
]
\draw[fill=gray!10] (0, 0) rectangle (5, 5);
\draw[fill=red!10] (5,0) -- (4.5,0) arc[start angle=0, delta angle=90, radius=4.5] 
    -- (0,4.5) -- (0,5) -- (5,5) -- cycle;
\draw (2.5,0) -- (2.5,5)
      (0,2.5) -- (5,2.5)
      (3.1820,3.1820) -- (5,5);
\pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in 
    {5/2.5, 5/5, 2.5/5, 5/0, 0/5, 4.5/0, 0/4.5, 3.7417/2.5, 2.5/3.7417} {
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\filldraw[black] (\x,\y) circle[radius=2pt];}\temp
}

\addplot[blue, only marks, mark=o, mark size=1pt] table {GPs.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I really can't thank you enough!!!!!!!!!!! Thank you ^^

Comment: Thanks to @Zarko for the idea of shortening the original code!